# Which constructed language (in spoken form) is most similar to a natural language?

Tags: constructed-languages

Another way to ask the titular question is: which constructed language could you actually speak and be understood by a speaker of a natural language (who doesn't also know the constructed language), i.e., could you "get by" in a country with said constructed language?

It is probably one of the *[a posteriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language#a_posteriori_language)* languages, such as [Occidental/Interlingue](http://interlingue.pbworks.com/w/page/4882389/FrontPage), [Interlingua](http://www.interlingua.com/), [Interslavic](http://steen.free.fr/interslavic/), [Folksprak](https://folksprak.org/wiki/doku.php), [Lingua Franca Nova](http://elefen.org/), or some other naturalistic language. Or perhaps even [Esperanto](http://esperanto.net/en/).

I consider this to be nearly the inverse of [this previously asked question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/which-language-is-most-similar-to-esperanto).

EDIT: The answer could inform a language learner which constructed language to study and provide additional motivation knowing that the language could be useful for oral communication with natural language speakers.

Comment: I guess, it depends on the country, where you want to "get by", and how close the constructed language is to the natural language of the country.

Comment: @Geshode "Get by" would mean speaking only the constructed language (assume fluency for the sake of this question) in the country and being understood enough to facilitate communication. Maybe along the lines of how some Spanish and Italians can communicate to varying degrees by speaking their native languages to each other (requires patience and concentration).

Comment: I am aware of that, hence my comment.

Comment: Thanks for link to Interslavic, it is amazing. I am a L1 Slavic speaker.